# How to Click on a button under Insert tag using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, css, xpath, webdriver

Need help in Clicking the Discontinue button inside a Insert Tag. Tried using Xpath, Name and Value. There is no ID in the Insert Tag

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[5]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/input")).click(); - did not work

```
<body>
<noscript/>
<!--/DO NOT REMOVE/-->
<!-- End SiteCatalyst code version: H.22. -->
<!--END HTML HEADER-->
<script type="text/javascript">   $(document).ready(function () { SLM.ON.FWF.HTMLPage.initialize(); }) </script>
<div class="DIVBackGround">
<div class="DIVPrimaryArea">
<noscript> <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="762"> <tr> <td width="324"></td> <td width="416"> <font color="red">Your browser's security settings do not allow JavaScript. You must change the settings to support JavaScript in order to use this application.</font> </td> </tr> </table> </noscript>
<!-- PARENT CONTAINER TO MANAGE WIDTH OF SECTIONS-->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<!--BEGIN HEADER-->
<table class="TableHeader" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="1012">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="1012">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="1012">
<!--END HEADER-->
<!--BEGIN WORKSPACE -->
<table class="TableBody" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="1012">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<form name="mainform" method="POST" action="/QUERY/?CharSet=ENGLISH&AppMode=SLM&TS=5%2f30%2f2017+10%3a53%3a26+AM" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<input name="SessionID" value="511036a7eec646b79ef2fe388928dd39" type="hidden"/>
<input name="StateID" value="431DCC44-5ED0-46EF-A42A-CB3FDE441083:3cbf085a-eb1a-4360-a35d-0c110a9593a0" type="hidden"/>
<input name="EntryPointName" value="" type="hidden"/>
<input name="Selection" value="SearchAgain" type="hidden"/>
<input name="Key" value="" type="hidden"/>
<input name="Name" value="" type="hidden"/>
<input name="PrevPage" value="ServicingLoanSummary" type="hidden"/>
<input name="PageStack" value="" type="hidden"/>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="762">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="762">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td/>
<td class="NavigationButtons" colspan="3">
<input class="ButtonLabel" name="btnDiscontinue" value="Discontinue" onclick="SLM.ON.QUERY.SubmitPage('Discontinue')" type="button"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What driver are you using (Chrome, Firefox, ...?), and do you get an error/exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this? `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value, 'Discontinue')]")).click();`

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your Response. I tried this. It doesn't work.

Comment: and replacing ´@value, 'Discontinue'´ by ´@type, 'button'´. It works?

Answer (score 0):

try using following:

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form table tr:nth-child(9) td>input")).click()
```

OR using JavaScriptExecutor

```
 WebElement yourElement = river.findElement(By.cssSelector("form table tr:nth-child(9) td>input"));
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click",yourElement);
```

Comment: Hi Kushal. thanks for your response. Both of these doesn't work

Comment: goto developer options > console > type `$$("form table tr:nth-child(9) td>input")` and share the result snapshot